# Exclude selected rows from results

Tags: excel, vba

I have never worked on vb scripts before. I have a requirement to generate insert statements based on some sample data in the excel sheet.

I have worked on one vb macro which is generating the results for all the columns in the sheet.

for example for two rows it will generate result as below:

```
insert into [Col1] ([col2], [col3], [col4], [col5c], [col6])
values
('ABC', 'PF', 'Loan_amount', 'GDTG/_Prod', 'IDW/logs'), 
('DFGC', 'PF', 'Investment', 'GDTG/_Prod', 'ERW/logs')
```

Now, i have a changed requirement.
I have added another column in the beginning which has some values like new, old, delete etc.

I want the insert to be generated only on the "new" marked rows.
For example in the below i want the result only for the new ones:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wett9.png)

Also, below is my current script:

```
Sub GetInsertSQL()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strQuery = ""
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        strQuery = strQuery + "[" + CStr(wsSrc.Cells(1, j)) + "], "
    Next j
    strQuery = Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 2)
    strQuery = "insert into [" + wsSrc.Name + "] (" + strQuery + ")"
    strOutput = strQuery + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + "values"

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        strQuery = ""
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            strQuery = strQuery + "'" + Replace(CStr(wsSrc.Cells(i, j).Text), "'", "''") + "', "
        Next j

        strQuery = "(" + Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 2) + "), "
        strOutput = strOutput + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + strQuery
    Next i

    strOutput = Left(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 2)
    OutputForm.txtOutput.Text = strOutput
    OutputForm.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub GetInsertSQL()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strQuery = ""
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        strQuery = strQuery + "[" + CStr(wsSrc.Cells(1, j)) + "], "
    Next j
    strQuery = Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 2)
    strQuery = "insert into [" + wsSrc.Name + "] (" + strQuery + ")"
    strOutput = strQuery + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + "values"

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        strQuery = ""
        'Adding this if condition to check if value in 1st column is New
        If (lcase(wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Text) = "new") Then
        For j = 1 To LastCol
                strQuery = strQuery + "'" + Replace(CStr(wsSrc.Cells(i, j).Text), "'", "''") + "', "
        Next j

        strQuery = "(" + Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 2) + "), "
        strOutput = strOutput + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + strQuery
        End If
    Next i

    strOutput = Left(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 2)
    OutputForm.txtOutput.Text = strOutput
    OutputForm.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @SRA !! Let me run this once and check

Comment: This is working fine except that i don't want first col in the insert statement which is just an indicator. Can we exclude that?

Comment: I made a change as J=2 and i am able to get the values from second column. However the insert statement still has that column name in the beginning --insert into [Table] ([Indicator], [col2],.....  Not able to figure out how to remove that?

Comment: Another question -- My workbook has 3 sheets but the insert data is actually in the sheet named "Input". Does it require any change in the script? Or Do i have to add this script by going to that particular sheet from the developer tab

Comment: Can you please clarify my doubts so that i can accept this answer.

Comment: To remove col1 from the header : start this loop with j=2   ::::                                      
  For j = 1 To LastCol
        strQuery = strQuery + "[" + CStr(wsSrc.Cells(1, j)) + "], "
    Next j

Comment: Thanks!! I happened to encounter the runtime-424 error. Object required when i copied the same macro in another workbook in sheet 4. (workbook has 4 sheets the        4th sheet has Input  data). Any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: In the first line, try changing  Set wsSrc = Activesheet to Set wsSrc = Sheets("Input")

Comment: OutputForm is probably a UserForm that was declared in the workbook where you copied this code from. You might want to look for that UserForm and create it in this workbook as well.

Comment: Also,how do you want the output? I guess if you delete the last 2 lines, your code would run without any error..  strOutput in the 3rd last line would have the SQL query you're looking for. What to do with this output string depends on your requirements.